# Don't we know how the magnetic field of the Sun is created?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, sun, plasma-physics, stellar-physics

This is how Wikipedia explains stellar magnetic fields:

> Stellar magnetic fields, according to solar dynamo theory, are caused
>   within the convective zone of the star. The convective circulation of
>   the conducting plasma functions like a dynamo. This activity destroys
>   the star's primordial magnetic field, then generates a dipolar
>   magnetic field. As the star undergoes differential rotation—rotating
>   at different rates for various latitudes—the magnetism is wound into a
>   toroidal field of "flux ropes" that become wrapped around the star. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_magnetic_field)

So this basically says that the solar magnetic field is driven by [heat convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer) which makes charged particle flows which create the solar magnetic field by [magnetohydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamics). The magnetic polarity of the Sun shifts every 11th year, because flux ropes are thought to become [wrapped around the Sun](https://wordlesstech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/The-Suns-Magnetic-Field-is-about-to-Flip-5.jpg).

But really we don't know the details on how the solar dynamo works, as Wikipedia states:

> The detailed mechanism of the solar dynamo is not known and is the
>   subject of current research. [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_dynamo)

It does not get any better if we look at the observations. We expected massive heat convection inside the Sun, driven by the temperature difference between the fusion powered [16 million degree hot core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core) and the huge temperature difference to the [5800 Kelvin hot photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere). But then the science of [helioseismology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helioseismology) came along and managed to interpret solar seismic waves and map the solar interior, and found no solar heat driven convection inside the Sun at all.

The first things helioseismology noticed was that most of the solar interior  rotates as one solid sphere, beneath the [tachocline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachocline), without any observable heat convection.  So they had to update the solar model and put the convection zone outside of the "solid" sphere:
[image]

But recently the measurements have become so good that we can even map the flows in the convection zone, and we have found a rather [tranquil "weather pattern", a double celled weather pattern](http://news.stanford.edu/news/2013/august/solar-magnetic-field-082913.html). And this weather pattern is not driven by heat convection, and heat convection is rather thought to slow the weather pattern down:

> The Sun’s meridional circulation is most likely mechanically driven
>   and thermally braked, roughly opposite to the driving mechanism of the
>   Hadley cell in the Earth’s atmosphere [source](http://hmi.stanford.edu/hminuggets/?p=467)

It seems like we don't know the details on how the solar dynamo theory works, and the solar dynamo theory even seems to be in conflict with the observations. Can we then claim that we know how the magnetic field of our Sun is created?

The magnetic field of the Sun shift magnetic polarity every 11th year. The current explanation on how this could be done is magnetic flux lines becoming magnetic flux ropes that winds up around the Sun due to difference in rotation, [as the photosphere rotate faster around equator than around the poles](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/656474main_solar-rotation_full.jpg). This somehow diminishes the existing magnetic field, and folding or fluxrope breaking is thought to reverse the magnetic polarity of the Sun. The details of this theory are neither well understood and is also a subject of current research.

It seems like stellar magnetic theory is in trouble, but there neither seems to be any good alternatives to research. If it only was as simple as the geomagnetic field. Earth has a solid inner iron/nickel core which can hold a permanent magnetic field, and our planets core has in [geological history changed magnetic polarity many times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_reversal). That is impossible at the Sun, as according to our solar model, the core is a 15 million degree hot plasma fusion furnace, and the observations of [solar neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino) confirms that the Sun is fusion powered. We could try things like moving all solar fusion to the millions of degrees hot solar corona, but that would be a violation of the current solar model. The solar corona do have a lot of magnetic reconnection in its hotspots, magnetic reconnection has spoiled many fusion experiments on Earth, but now it seems like they are starting to use magnetic reconnection to create fusion:

> In fusion facilities, reconnection can help start and confine the
>   plasma that fuels fusion reactions. [source](http://www.pppl.gov/news/2017/01/pppl-physicist-uncovers-clues-mechanism-behind-magnetic-reconnection)

But such a suggestion is just topsy turvey, or is it?

Comment: This (very well crafted) question is definitely verging on 'too broad'.  But it sounds like you want to know, "what is the current status of solar dynamo theory?"  Because there are numerous, really good questions in here; it might be good to break this up into numerous `Questions`.

Comment: +1 lovely question(s)...... but you could split into 5/6  for sure, and maybe sumarise the present questions at the end of this post.

Comment: Small-scale fields (i.e., near active regions and sunspots), yes.  Large-scale fields, not really...

Comment: @honeste_vivere Thanks! We might know how sunspot fields are created, but we neither know all the details either. Sunspots kind of remind me of big thunderclouds, thunderclouds also have convection, and can play with magnetic fields. [The fermi satelite got connected with a fluxline from a thundercloud in the middle of Africa, and received positrons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wv6UANDKCcA). I red some papers on it, and the ultra fast electrons creating positrons theory can't explain the magnitude of the observations. Fusion often creates antimatter and was their first proposed solution.

Comment: @honeste_vivere The nuclear reaction mystery of large thunderclouds, have some interesting observations, [neutrons emissions](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/409/1/012216), [clouds of antimatter](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/205547-antimatter-cloud-found-after-pilot-takes-wrong-turn-into-thunderstorm), increased deuterium in hail from thunderstorms, gamma rays. [I found a related question.](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-lightning-cause-fusion-or-does-it) And this is only the tranquil Earth, not the huge energetic Sun.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I looked some more, terrestrial gamma ray flashes are above thunderclouds, and solar gamma ray flares are above Sunspots. Both TGF's and Flares release [antimatter](http://www.sci-news.com/physics/science-antimatter-positron-solar-flares-01206.html), and [neutrons](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1384107614001936). So it seems like a matching correlation, we just lack some sunspot lightning... Lightning on planets can be observed by radio wave emission... [sunspots  have strong radio emission](https://phys.org/news/2010-08-sunspots-source-radio-emissions.html)

Comment: The correlation might even be bigger. ["According to the Relativistic Runaway Electron Avalanche (RREA) model, a population of seed electrons from cosmic ray extensive air showers (CREAS) is required to initiate a lightning discharge."](http://www.nssl.noaa.gov/users/mansell/icae2014/preprints/Lindy_152.pdf) There may be a possibility that the observed extensive particle shower below thunderclouds is not created by cosmic rays, but by magnetic reconnection, creating jets, as seen above sunspots (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNsSQjSzLv0). Magnetic reconnection might then trigger lightning.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I have some problems composing questions as I am so easily carried away by my excitement and often end up going off topic. If you find this remarkable correlation between sunspots and thunderclouds interesting, I would greatly appreciate it if you could post it, or parts of it, as a question:-)

Comment: @EnosOye - The gamma rays produced during solar flares most likely result from bremsstrahlung radiation and spallation.  As for TGFs, they do not directly observe positrons, they observe ~0.5 MeV photons corresponding to those released during pair annihilation.  I am skeptical of the fusion answer, more likely that pairs are produced (perhaps by large electric fields?) and then annihilate.  Perhaps a very small number of atoms could fuse but I doubt it would be enough to explain TGFs.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Fusion or not, there still seem to be many correlations in the observations between Sunspots and thundercloud systems. Fermi acted as a positron receiver from a TGF and emitted 511keV gamma rays, and documented their bounce, so that seems to be good proof. I have not concluded if there is fusion or not, but it seems like a good possibility, and there are papers written about it (https://www.astro.umd.edu/~share/publications/kozlovsky_04.pdf), (http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1974ApJ...193..729R). At least there seems to be good fusion fuel available.

Comment: The problems with observing fusion is that we can't usually see fully ionized particles.  The Van Allen belts was not known until our spacecrafts got hit by them, the Themis satellites found out the magnetic reconnection in Earths plasma tail was hundreds of times more energetic than expected, with high plasma concetrations, plasmoids and counter flowing currents/particle jets, which fusion scientists only dream about.

Comment: @EnosOye - Be careful not to read too much into the press releases for science stories.  Having had several of my papers turned into press releases, I can tell you that the press releases often phrase things in hyperbolic and/or misleading fashions to get more clicks.  There is also an unfortunate trend of dramatizing results to boost citations.  As a side note, I work in space plasmas and we routinely resolve the entire 3D velocity distribution of ionized particles.

Comment: @honeste_vivere Some press releases might be exaggerated to get attention, other times it seems like they can be used to actually convey what the scientists believe and are enthusiastic about. Papers can be accurate and helpful, but are often dry and time consuming. Accepted theory can also become "truth", which often makes it more challenging to get alternative theory through. I talked to a guy, who published papers about a Mercury probe which observed a massive wave of neutrons coming from a solar flare, and he was amazed by the amount of scientists that tried to discredit the observations.

Comment: @honeste_vivere There seems to be a debate if it is fusion or photonuclear reactions which create both the observed neutrons and positrons related to both flares and TGF's. I don't know the final outcome of this debate, but I do know that the observations of Sunspot systems and thundercloud systems show remarkable similarities,  and this correlation might lead to an explanation of both phenomena. I will have a go at phrasing a question.

Comment: There are plenty of problematic statements in this "question" that seem to be your interpretation alone. For example "But then the science of helioseismology came along and managed to interpret solar seismic waves and map the solar interior, and found no solar heat driven convection inside the Sun at all." is simply incorrect.

Comment: Is there an actual "good" model of the Sun electro magnetic engine?

Answer (score 1):

Well the sun gets its magnetic field from moving charged particles. However it can not be replicated on Earth for a long time. It requires a lot of energy. The sun gets all its energy by fusion reactions. Also the Earth's magnetic field does not come from a solid layer of nickel and iron. The Earth outer core is too hot for that. Instead the liquid iron outer core swirls and tiny temperature changes in the Earth's outer core creates a runaway effect causing Earth to get its magnetic field. The sun gets its magnetic field from charged particles(protons and electrons).

https://www.space.com/22393-sun-magnetic-field-explained-infographic.html